# How can I setup subdomain on DO NGINX droplet?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, digital-ocean

I have a droplet at DigitalOcean, I used the one-click install with LEMP on Ubuntu.

I've been having trouble with adding a subdomain. Here is what I'm doing.

1. I set up the domain and pointed it to my server.
2. I also created an A record for my subdomain sub.mydomain.com
3. I created a new directory for my subdomain using the following comand: sudo mkdir -p /var/www/sub.mydomain.com/html
4. I also did this: sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/sub.mydomain.com/html
5. I created a new server block using the following command:
   sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/sub.mydomain.com
6. Here I'm trying to modify my server block and I think this is where I'm doing something wrong

   ```
   ##
   # You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
   # of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
   # http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
   # http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
   # http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
   #
   # Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
   # file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
   #
   # Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
   ##

   # Default server configuration
   #
   server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;

   # SSL configuration
   #
   # listen 443 ssl default_server;
   # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
   #
   # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
   # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
   #
   # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
   # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
   #
   # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
   # Don't use them in a production server!
   #
   # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

   root /var/www/html;

   # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
   index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

   server_name sub.mydomain.com;

   location / {
       # First attempt to serve request as file, then
       # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

   # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
   #
   #location ~ \.php$ {
   #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   #
   #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
   #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   #   # With php7.0-fpm:
   #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   #}

   # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
   # concurs with nginx's one
   #
   #location ~ /\.ht {
   #   deny all;
   #}
   }


   # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
   #
   # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
   # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
   #
   #server {
   #   listen 80;
   #   listen [::]:80;
   #
   #   server_name example.com;
   #
   #   root /var/www/example.com;
   #   index index.html;
   #
   #   location / {
   #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   #   }
   #}
   ```

What exactly am I doing wrong? What should I include in the server block file?

Answer (score 0):

Should you change:

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

To:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
```

and then add symbolic link to:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

command:

```
$ cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/sub.mydomain.com
```

Hope help your issue

Comment: are your restart your nginx?